# What does these two "median" words mean in this Page Speed Test result?

Tags: performance, page-speed, optimization

Here is a copy:

- First paragraph

  > Data from the Chrome User Experience Report indicates this page's
  >   **median** FCP (1.7s) and DCL (1.8s) ranks it in the middle third of all pages. This page has a medium level of optimization because some
  >   of its resources are render-blocking. Learn more.
- Second paragraph

  > PSI estimates this page requires 0 render-blocking round trips and ~11
  >   resources (0.2MB) to load. The **median** page requires 4
  >   render-blocking round trips and ~75 resources (1MB) to load. Fewer
  >   round trips and bytes results in faster pages.

I am not a native English speaker. And I am even more confused after reading many times.

In the first paragraph, does it mean that **most people** have an FCP of 1.7s and DCL of 1.8s? If so, how does Google know that?

In the second paragraph, does it mean that most of the other web pages require 4 render-blocking round trips and ~75 resources?

I'd be very appreciated if someone could dive into details of these two reports above.

Thanks,

Comment: ***...denoting or relating to a value or quantity lying at the midpoint of a frequency distribution of observed values or quantities...***

Comment: Median math concept explained including a graph: https://skillstairway.com/what-is-median-and-how-to-calculate-it/    You still have an open question about how Google knows this information though.

Comment: Median is a calculation formula for working out an 'average', there are many different types of average formulas such as mean, mode and median.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks. And yes, I do want to know how Google knows it. Do you have any ideas?